# Automate uploading files in django admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-admin

I have a database model that in the Django model all I need to do is upload an image file to a new database record. Is there anyway I can automate this as I have a lot of images to upload? All images will come from a folder on my computer and each picture will be added to a new database record. All help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please add more details. Where does the file that has to be saved come from? Which database record do you have to save to?

Comment: Okay, if you need any more info, let me know :)

Comment: Why dont you just run a simple query?

Comment: The images aren't in the database yet, I'm trying to get them in.

Comment: You could write a script to insert images in your table.

Comment: does this solve your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run a simple script to save files stored in a particular folder

```
from django.core.files import File

class MyModel(models.Model):
    picture=models.ImageField()


MyModel.picture.save('abc.png', File(open('/tmp/pic.png', 'r')))
```

To do this for all files in a directory -

```
BASE_PATH = '/home/somefolder' 
files = os.listdir(BASE_PATH)
for file in files:
    MyModel.picture.save(file, File(open(os.path.join(BASE_PATH, file), 'r')))
```

Comment: Will I have to write that line of code for every item in the folder?

Comment: No you could put this in a loop and run it for all files in the folder.